# Idea 13 highlighting playframework 2 routes

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I tried everything, but idea 13 still highlighting routes. The application is deployed and it is all right:
[image]

as you can see i tried also mark as code classes_managed and src_managed(Classes too). I also have installed the plugins scala and play 2 support

**UPDATE**

[image: update]

Comment: Could you give a screenshot of the project structure ? In mine, I have as sources : app and src_managed/main  and as resources : resources_managed and conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You excluded resource_managed which should be marked as "resource".

More generally, a play 2 project structure must be :

[image]